# Is there any way to update editorState of Draftjs only if it is different with Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, draftjs

When I update the editorState, I save it in Redux because I would like to be able to modify it from another component as well.
However, `state1.getCurrentContent() !== editorState.getCurrentContent()` return true while it is the same what causes a new update and puts the cursor back to position 0 when I write.
I tried to compare them after `convertToRaw()` but same result.

Is there a way to do this correctly? Or I have to create a boolean variable in my reducer to indicate if I have to change my editorState or not.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks.

```js
function RichEditor({ _id}) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const editor = useRef(null);
  const content = useSelector((state) => state.reducer.mail[_id]);
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(EditorState.createEmpty());

  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    if (content) {
      let state1 = EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromRaw(content));
      const state = state1.getCurrentContent() !== editorState.getCurrentContent()
        ? EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromRaw(content))
        : EditorState.createEmpty();
      setEditorState(state);
    }
  }, [content]);

  const handleEditorState = (contentState) => {
    setEditorState(contentState);
    let raw = convertToRaw(contentState.getCurrentContent());
    dispatch({ type: "SET_MAIL_ITEM", tabId: _id, item: "body", value: raw });
  };

  return (
      <div onClick={focusEditor}>
        <Editor
          ref={editor}
          editorState={editorState}
          onChange={handleEditorState}
          placeholder=""
        />
      </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: how you handle SET_MAIL_ITEM event

Comment: Like this in my reducer
```
case "SET_MAIL_ITEM":
      return {
        ...state,
        mail: {
          ...state.mail,
          [action.tabId]: {
            ...state.mail[action.tabId],
            [action.item]: action.value,
          },
        },
      };
```